# django rest framework валидация json данных

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

Серверу приходит json формата:

```
{
    "type": "string",
    "object": {
        "lead_id": int,
        "form_name": "string",
        "answers": [
            {
                "lead_id": int,
                "key": "string",
            }
            ...
        ]
    },
    "group_id": int,
    "secret": "string"
}
```

Как с помощью django REST framework сделать валидацию данного json?

[en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167246/django-rest-framework-validate-json-data) версия

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример решения проблемы:

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class VkObjectSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    lead_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    group_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    form_id = serializers.IntegerField()


class VkBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    object = VkObjectSerializer()

    group_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    secret = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

# view.py
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import VkBaseSerializer


class VkCallbackView(CreateAPIView):
    # не понял как сделать проверку до вызова `create`
    serializer_class = VkBaseSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Метод который проверяет json 
        """
        valid_ser = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if valid_ser.is_valid():
            return Response('True')
        return Response('False')
```

Валидные данные выглядят так:

```
>>> valid_ser.data
{
    "type": "str",
    "object": {
        "lead_id": 123,
        "group_id": 12345,
        "user_id": 12352,
        "form_id": 1
    },
    "group_id": 5123,
    "secret": "str"
}
```

---

Очень помогли ответы:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37629684/6623896 - задать модель json
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085153/how-to-validate-a-json-object-in-django - проверить данные в View